# Disable jQuery draggable in child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable). I have added draggable function to main div. Now in all the child elements it's also draggable. How can I disable dragging inside child div if parent is draggable?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: black solid 2px;
}

.noDrag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: blue solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
  <div class='noDrag'>No Drag</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix this use the [`cancel` property](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel), and provide it a selector to match the element you want to disable the drag behaviour on, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    cancel: '.noDrag'
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: black solid 2px;
}

.noDrag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: blue solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
  <div class="noDrag">No Drag</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use cancel or disableselection() like suggest in jQuery-ui documentation https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Handles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable, #draggable2 { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
  #draggable p { cursor: move; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ handle: "p" });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ cancel: "p.ui-widget-header" });
    $( "div, p" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p class="ui-widget-header">I can be dragged only by this handle</p>
</div>
 
<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>You can drag me around&hellip;</p>
  <p class="ui-widget-header">&hellip;but you can't drag me by this handle.</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```